# Payment gateway response back to application .net

Tags: .net, json, api

I don't have much experience in handling with the api's. I have integrated a POST Json API with in my application which send out email to the customer for the online payment .Everything work well till this and there is a parameter field for the disclosure URL, to which the response from the API will be posted after the payment is done.I want to develop one page in my .net C# application(frame work 4.5) for capturing this response . Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: and this page has to return http 200 !!

Comment: "eci":"7",
"postdate":"0308",
"trackid":"J8UE3",
"tranid":"123456789",
"udf1":"MAR082017",
"udf3":"Fname Lname",
"udf2":"abcd@abc.com",
"result":"CAPTURED",
"responsecode":"00",
"paymentid":"987654654231548",
"auth":"875837",
"ref":"706710566334",
"udf4":"99977755"  
this is the response from the API